# extracting data from sql 2008 to excel with VB6

Tags: sql, excel, vb6

Okay, I will paste in the code below. I'm trying to loop through the table in sql server 2008 but when excel opens up in only shows me the data for the first row in the table. How do I extend the loop to show me all the records in the table. The record count is 13, but i see only data ffor the first row (firstname, lastname)

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim X As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim strReportFileName As String
Dim strTmpMsg As String
Dim intResponse As Integer
Dim xlRow As Integer

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add

xlSheet.Name = "Test Extract"

With xlSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
End With
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
strSQL = "SELECT FirstName, LastName from dbo.tblTest_clients"
rs.Open strSQL, g_cnDatabase
Debug.Print strSQL
MsgBox rs.RecordCount

rs.MoveFirst

For y = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Select Case y
        Case 0
            With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, y + 1)
                If Not IsNull(rs("FirstName").Value) Then
                    .Value = rs("FirstName")
                End If
            End With
        Case 1
            With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, y + 1)
                If Not IsNull(rs("LastName").Value) Then
                    .Value = rs("LastName")
                End If
            End With
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
Next y

If xlApp.Version = "10.0" Then
    strReportFileName = g_strReportWriteDir & "\ClientInfo" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDDHHNNSS") & ".xls "
    xlBook.SaveAs strReportFileName
Else
    strReportFileName = g_strReportWriteDir & "\ClientInfo" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDDHHNNSS") & ".xls"
    xlBook.SaveAs strReportFileName, 56
End If

xlBook.Close
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
'xlApp.Quit

strTmpMsg = "Client Info Extract File: " & strReportFileName & " was created successfully."
intResponse = MsgBox(strTmpMsg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to View?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Viewing the Extract opens another program windo -please be sure to CLOSE it once you are done reviewing the extract.", vbYesNo, "Client Extract View Confirmation.....")
    If intResponse = vbYes Then
        If ShellEx(strReportFileName, essSW_SHOWMAXIMIZED, , , "Open", frmReports.hWnd) Then
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: You need to wrap your `for` loop inside a `while not rs.EOF` or `while rs.EOF = False`, and just before the `end while` add an `rs.MoveNext`.

Comment: I did that actually, but when excel opens up it then only shows the last record it looped through. Either way I only get one First name, and one last name. I went line by line and it looped through all the names.

Comment: Then you're putting the loop in the wrong place. Put it immediately before the `for` loop. What you've posted now simply writes the content of the first row.

Answer (score 2):

```
rs.MoveFirst

With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow)
    .Cells(1).Value = "First Name"
    .Cells(2).Value = "Last Name"
End With
xlRow = xlRow + 1

Do While Not rs.EOF
    With xlSheet.Cells(xlRow)
        If Not IsNull(rs("FirstName").Value) Then .Cells(1).Value = rs("FirstName")
        If Not IsNull(rs("LastName").Value) Then .Cells(2).Value = rs("LastName")
    End With
    rs.movenext
    xlRow = xlRow + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You never set `xlRow` to any value or iterate over it, so the code is going to just keep writing to that row - hence, why you only see the last value in your.
2. You can do what you want with much cleaner code.

See Below

```
rs.MoveFirst

xlRow = 1

Do Until rs.EOF

   'puts first name in column A
   If Not IsNull(rs("FirstName")) Then xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, 1).Value = rs("FirstName")
   'puts last name in column B
   If Not IsNull(rs("LastName")) Then xlSheet.Cells(xlRow, 2).Value = rs("LastName")

    rs.MoveNext
    xlRow = xlRow + 1

Loop
```